# Diagonal in a parallelogram.

Tags: geometry

If I know know alpha in parallelogram and draw the diagonal between the beta angles , how can I determine the two angles that the diagonal divides beta ?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is the other angle, then you don't have enough information: the scale of the parallelogram matters as well. But you should define your terms in the question: you should not expect people to guess.

Comment: To clarify, I draw a parallelogram with the two smaller angles being alpha and the two larger being beta, then I draw the diagonal from beta to beta , this will divide beta in two angles. Alpha is known how can I determine the two angles the diagonal forms. I would as a picture but I'm not allowed.

Comment: You cannot: you have to know $\alpha$ ($\beta$ is then known: $\beta=180^{\circ} - \alpha$, and two independent lengths: the base and an adjacent side or the base and the height e.g.